# Stable server name for an EC2 instance

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm an EC2 newbie and I noticed that the address (like `ec2-NN-NNN-NN-NN.compute-1.amazonaws.com`) of the instance changes, when I shutdown and re-start it.

On the instance, there is an Apache Tomcat app server and after each restart I need to modify its URL in my client application.

What is the easiest way to ensure that the URL of the app server (hosted on EC2) remains constant after restarting the instance?

Comment: Try http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2

Answer (score 4):

Launch your instance inside a [VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/). The IP / DNS address never changes on the internal subnet. Let a load balancer balance between the nodes (assuming you have more than one) on the pubic subnet. Add a `CNAME` entry and point it to the load balancer using **route 53** and let the client point its target address to the `CNAME` entry.

Note that you are limited to 5 elastic IPs on EC2 (getting more is subject to permission) and you will be charged for additional IPs.

Answer (score 3):

Get an elastic IP and then associate it with your instance.
However, if instance is shutdown and restarted, you might lose the association. You will just have to re-associate it again.

Answer (score 2):

Public DNS and Private DNS of the Amazon EC2 changes whenever the EC2 instance is restarted in the classic AWS cloud. Attach ElasticIP to the Amazon EC2 instance and configure the EIP in R53 or other DNS.

In future you are planning to have multiple Apache EC2, then attach them to Amazon ELB and point the ELB CNAME in the DNS or R53.

Comment: If I own a domain name like `myapp.com`, is it possible to configure Tomcat such that it uses it (i. e. the server is available via `http://myapp.com` regardless of its public and private DNSes) ?